# Spark Scala merging multiple columns to single column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking to merge 2 separate rows into one in spark scala. I have tried group by mechanisms but its not working out.

Input:

```
col1       col2  col3   col4    col5
2023-02-27  LHR  SFO    931 
2023-02-27  LHR  SFO             977
```

Expected output:

```
col1        col2    col3    col4    col5
2023-02-27  LHR     SFO      931    977
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the logic you are looking for. However, the idea seems to group by a certain number of columns and aggregate the others ignoring null values.

This could be done like this:

```scala
val df = Seq(
    ("2023-02-27", "LHR", "SFO", Some("931"), None ),
    ("2023-02-27", "LHR", "SFO", None, Some("977"))
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")

df.groupBy("col1", "col2", "col3")
  .agg(first('col4, ignoreNulls=true) as "col4",
       first('col5, ignoreNulls=true) as "col5"
  ).show()
```

```
+----------+----+----+----+----+                                                
|      col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----------+----+----+----+----+
|2023-02-27| LHR| SFO| 931| 977|
+----------+----+----+----+----+
```